# Next JS bootstrapping

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Where is the best place to bootstrap my Next JS application? Currently I'm doing this at the start of my `_app.tsx` component. Will these be set before `getInitialProps` is called on the server?

```js
// pages/_app.js
import axios from 'axios'
import NextApp from 'next/app'
import React from 'react'

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; // Set axios defaults

const App extends NextApp {
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Next.js initializes **all** pages from `_app.tsx`.

If you don't need `axios` on every single page, it's not optimal to add it here.

You can create a helper module in a separate file where you would configure `axios` defaults. Then call this helper where you need it in a component or page.

Answer (score -2):

You just npm i react-bootstrap in your app. After, you use components from [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/alerts).

If you like to use only css from bootstrap, you just copy css you need in /styles.css

P.S. you dont need to define it somewhere, it's just standard library, it will be initialized by itself.

Answer (score -2):

npm package:

Bootstrap for react/nextjs [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction)

In this case you will use elements of the lib above.

CSS:
If you only need `CSS`, you can just import `bootstrap.css` to your `app.tsx` like this

```
import "../styles/your_bootstrap_file.css";
```

Download bootstrap.css [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/)